# Object.bindProperties() Method of Nashorn

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I have two questions about the Object.bindProperties() method in Nashorn:

1. Is there a comprehensive documentation for this method, except at https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-loadWithNewGlobal ?
2. Is it a bug as shown below?

The following code does not bind the x, y, and z properties of obj2 to obj because obj already has properties with the same names. Is it documented somewhere?

```
var obj = {x:10, y:20, z:30};
var obj2 = {x:100, y:200, z:300};

// bind properties of 'obj2' to 'obj'
Object.bindProperties(obj, obj2); 

print(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);  
print(obj2.x, obj2.y, obj2.z);  
---------------------------------
10 20 30
100 200 300
--------------------------------
```

Now, let us add a new property to obj2. The new property is bound to obj, but obj reads the new property's value as null:

```
var obj = {x:10, y:20, z:30};
var obj2 = {x:100, y:200, z:300};

// Add a new property to obj2
obj2.u = 600;

// bind properties of 'obj2' to 'obj'
Object.bindProperties(obj, obj2); 

print(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z, obj.u);  // obj.u is null. Why?
print(obj2.x, obj2.y, obj2.z, obj2.u);  

---------------------------------
10 20 30 null
100 200 300 600
--------------------------------
```

And, here is another variant of the code that works. This time, I started the target object as empty. Now, adding the new property to the source works fine.

```
var obj = {};
var obj2 = {x:100, y:200, z:300};

// Add a new property to obj2
obj2.u = 600;

// bind properties of 'obj2' to 'obj'
Object.bindProperties(obj, obj2); 

print(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z, obj.u);  // obj.u is correct.It is 600
print(obj2.x, obj2.y, obj2.z, obj2.u);  

----------------------------
100 200 300 600
100 200 300 600
----------------------------
```

I am using JDK version 1.8.0_20.

Thanks
Kishori

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a comprehensive documentation for this method,

I think the only one is at the URL that you provided. Here's a [link](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Object.bindProperties) that takes you directly to the documentation for the method.

> The following code does not bind the x, y, and z properties of obj2 to obj because obj already has properties with the same names. Is it documented somewhere?

Yes, it is mentioned in the documentation:

> If the target object **already contains** a property called "foo", the source's "foo" is **skipped** (not bound). (emphases mine)

<s>I didn't see the issue where a new property was mapped to `null`; It seemed to work for me. I'm using JDK 1.8.0_25.</s> I read this wrong. The reason you are seeing `null` is that the source object has no idea that you added a new property to `obj2`. There is no property called `u` on `obj`, and so it will display `null`. The source object doesn't "track" the destination object and vice-versa.

There are a few other caveats. `bindProperties` only does a shallow copy. So if you have nested objects, and you modify a property on the source object, it will be reflected in the destination object. For example:

```
var test = {
    a: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        z: 10
    }
};
print("test0:" + JSON.stringify(test, null, 4));

test.b = {};
Object.bindProperties(test.b, test.a);
print("test1:" + JSON.stringify(test, null, 4));

test.b.y = 100;
print("test2:" + JSON.stringify(test, null, 4))
```

Yields:

```
test0:{
    "a": {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 10,
        "z": 10
    }
}
test1:{
    "a": {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 10,
        "z": 10
    },
    "b": {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 10,
        "z": 10
    }
}
test2:{
    "a": {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 100,
        "z": 10
    },
    "b": {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 100,
        "z": 10
    }
}
```

This may or may not be what you need; it wasn't what I wanted and so it was a source of surprise. Although once I read the documentation in some more detail, I guess I should have expected to be surprised based on this comment:

> It is recommended that the bound properties be treated as non-configurable properties to avoid surprises.